# iCalendar File Format (ICS) repeat an event every 2 weeks on Sun, except for the 3rd Sun of the Month

Tags: icalendar

Is it possible to do this?

This will repeat every 2 weeks:

```
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2;WKST=SU
```

This will repeat on every 1st/3rd/5th Sun:

```
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU,3SU,5SU
```

What I need is something like this (every 2 weeks, except 3rd Sun):

```
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2;WKST=SU;BYDAY=-3SU
```

Comment: To help you design your rule, would be good if you could give examples with dates

FYI, your last rule is not allowed as per [RFC5545 §3.3.10](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5545#section-3.3.10)

> The **BYDAY rule part MUST
      NOT be specified with a numeric value when the FREQ rule part is
      not set to MONTHLY or YEARLY**.  Furthermore, the BYDAY rule part
      MUST NOT be specified with a numeric value with the FREQ rule part
      set to YEARLY when the BYWEEKNO rule part is specified.

Comment: I understand the final rule is not allowed.  It was an example of what I'd like to achieve.

The example dates are:
Jul 3
Jul 17
(NOT Jul 31)
Aug 14
Aug 28
Sep 11
Sep 25
Oct 9
Oct 23

Comment: it seems that the only option with a RRULE to achieve what you want would be to leverage the EXRULE which has been deprecated in RFC5545 but that at never really reached broad support before.